# Formatting or initializing a partition from the command-line in Haiku

Tags: command-line, formatting, haiku

I'm making a script and I want to take an existing partition and clear it quickly.  Rather than using `rm` I thought there might be a command-line way of formatting or initializing a partition, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mkfs -t bfs /dev/disk/ata/0/master/raw
```

Comment: I don't want to trash my whole disk...will this also work on `/dev/disk/ata/0/master/3` even though it doesn't seem to have a `raw` subdir if I try autocomplete in a Terminal?